# Find $K$ when $p_X(k)=0.5$ and $X \sim \text{hypergeom}(N,K,n)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, factorial

A random variable ${\displaystyle X}$ follows the hypergeometric distribution if its probability mass function (pmf) is given by

$p_{X}(k)=\operatorname{Pr}(X=k)=\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
K \\
k
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
N-K \\
n-k
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{l}
N \\
n
\end{array}\right)}$

It is written ${\textstyle X\sim \operatorname {Hypergeometric} (N,K,n)}$.

I am trying to map the random variable $X$ to another binary random variable $Y$ as follows:

> $Y=0 $ if $X=0 $ else $Y=1$.

Moreover, I want $Y$ to have a uniform distribution. I am trying to figure out what value of $K$ can lead to this.

In summary, my question can be stated as below:

**What value of $K$ (exactly or approximately) in terms of $N$ and $n$ results in $p_{X}(0)=\operatorname{Pr}(X=0)=1/2?$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the binomial approximation to the hypergeometric distribution,
$$
P(X=0)\approx P\big(\operatorname{Bin}(n,\tfrac{K}{N})=0\big)=(1-K/N)^n
$$
For this to be equal to $1/2$, we would need
$$
\boxed{K= N\cdot(1- 2^{-1/n}).}
$$
More precisely, $K$ would need to be the closest integer to $N(1-2^{-1/n})$.

This only works if the binomial distribution is a good approximation to the hypergeometric distribution. According to [Holmes], the error in this approximation is at most $\frac{n-1}{N-1}$. Therefore, for the above value of $K$, the hypergeometric probability will be withing $\frac{n-1}{N-1}$ of $\frac12$, which is very close as long as $N$ is large compared to $n$.

> Holmes, S. (2004). *Stein’s method for birth and death chains.* In Stein’s method: expository lectures and applications, vol. 46 of IMS Lecture Notes Monogr. Ser. Inst. Math.
> Statist., Beachwood, OH, 45–67